# Formulas in Ms Access

Tags: database, excel, ms-access

I Need To write some formulas to calculate Field Value based on other fields values ( as like as what we do in excel ) , What is the best way to do it ? could you please recommend references ? thanks

Comment: Do you mean within the SQL of a query or within some code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/

If you are using MS Access in Design mode the online help and the code completion are quite good, they will guide you to make almost effortless.

Answer (score 0):

You should give more details about what you want the formulas to do.

In short though you can enter formula sin the query design like this

```
NewColumnName: (value / formula)
```

When referencing other fields you want to include them in []

So you can say :

```
NewColumnName: [Column1] + 5
```

Finally if you plan to sart usng excel If statements, note that the syntax is similear but it's called IIF so it would be like:

```
NewColumnName: IIF( [Column1] > 0 , "Positive","Negitive")
```